# grails - unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, grails-domain-class

I have difficulty in making unit testing on the method contained in the domain like this:

This is the domain class

```
class UserRole implements Serializable {

    User user
    Role role

        static void removeAll(User user) {
          executeUpdate 'DELETE FROM UserRole WHERE user=:user', [user: user]
        }
}
```

Then in the service :

```
class CorporateUserService {
   def delete (def cifUserInstance) {
    def userDetail,users,userRole
    userDetail=UserDetails.findById(cifUserInstance.userDetails.id)
    users=User.findById(userDetail.user.id)
    userRole=UserRole.removeAll(users)
   }
}
```

And in unit test:

```
void testDelete(){
   def cifUserService = new CorporateUserService()
   mockDomain(UserRole,[])
   def newuserRole2=UserRole.create(user,role2)
   def newuserRole=UserRole.create(user,role)
   newuserRole.executeUpdate 'DELETE FROM UserRole WHERE user= :user',[user: user]
    try{
        cifUserInstance = cifUserService.delete(cifUser)
    }
    catch(RuntimeException e){
        println e
    }
}
```

I have an error like this :

> "groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:
>   No signature of method:
>   com.logika.corp.security.UserRole.executeUpdate()
>   is applicable for argument types:
>   (java.lang.String,
>   java.util.LinkedHashMap) values:
>   [DELETE FROM UserRole WHERE user=
>   :user, [user:user1]]"

Can anyone know how to fix this error??

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that Grails adds a lot of dynamic methods at runtime. The mockDomain() method adds the dynamic findBy... methods etc, but it doesn't add the executeUpdate dynamic method.

So you have a couple of choices

1/ Move your unit test to the integration test folder. That way grails creates a full runtime environment and will add all the dynamic classes. (at the expense of a slower running time)

or

2/ Mock out the behaviour of the executeUpdate so that you are just testing your own code. (You don't necessarily want to unit test the grails code?)
e.g.

```
registerMetaClass(UserRole )
UserRole.metaClass.static.executeUpdate={String query, Map items-> println "Mocking executeUpdate"}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
newuserRole.executeUpdate 'DELETE FROM UserRole WHERE user= :user',user
```

seen [here](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeUpdate.html)

I hope it helps!